# jQuery: box-shadow blinks when div animates on a large size screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, screen-resolution, css

I'm trying to animate a `div`

```
background: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

$("#foo").animate({"top":"0px"},{duration:800});
```

As the div is being animated, its `box-shadow` starts blinking - http://jsfiddle.net/TvKqx/

Is there anything I can do to make the animation smoother?

**UPDATES:**
I have a screen resolution of 1440 X 900 and I think that is where the problem comes from. After switching the screen resolution to 1024 X 768 the blinking is gone and the animation works fine. So how can I enhance jQuery animations on large size screen?

Comment: I can't seem to see the problem, tried both in Chrome and Firefox. Animates fine for me.

Comment: @sQVe that is weird o.O ..can this be a hardware problem?

Comment: Same, tried it in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE9 and can't see the problem. (but I did add in some vendor codes `-moz`, `-o-` and `-webkit` to the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TvKqx/1/

Comment: @Arch Most likely. What kind of hamster-wheel machine do you have?

Comment: @sQVe Mine is a desktop with an AMD A6-6650 APU processor and a RAM of 8GB. My graphic adaptor comes together with my CPU, it is a Radeon(tm) HD Graphics @ 2.60GHz. And my monitor is a 16-inch Samsung Syncmaster 920NW. Personally I don't think there should be a problem regarding the hardware...

Comment: I think I have figured it out.. The blinking only occurs to large size screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `transition` for larger screens - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TvKqx/9/embedded/result/)

```css
#foo {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    top: 0;

    -webkit-transition: top .8s linear;
       -moz-transition: top .8s linear;
            transition: top .8s linear;
}
```